# how can i get a high quality picture from a view’s screenshots

Tags: android

I want to get the picture of the view（not ImageView） inside，but the picture I got was not clear,Of course the original picture is clear ,here is my codes

```
public static Bitmap getDrawBitmap(View designView){
        designView.destroyDrawingCache();
        designView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        designView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
        return designView.getDrawingCache();
}
```

I have tried to scale the View,and then getDrawingCache(),but it didn't work,the view's size didn't change

```
Bitmap bitmap=ImgUtils.getDrawBitmap(testBtn);
float w=1260f;
float h=1660f;

float x= w/(bitmap.getWidth()/DrawAttribute.density);
float y= h/(bitmap.getHeight()/DrawAttribute.density);

Log.e("x-y",x+"-"+y);
Bitmap result=Bitmap.createBitmap(1260,1660,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas offScreen = new Canvas(result);
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(x,y);
offScreen.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
//存储路径
OutputStream stream = null;
try {
     if (LiApplication.creatDir()) {
           stream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/yc/img/"
                                        + "save.png");
                    } 
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                }

     Bitmap.CompressFormat format = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG;
     result.compress(format, 100, stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Demo code for taking screen shot of whole View.

```
 View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.myView);
  Bitmap mybitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        v.getChildAt(0).getWidth(), 
        v.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), 
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas c = new Canvas(mybitmap);
  iv.getChildAt(0).draw(c);

  //remember here View may be any view including ScrollView or what ever it may be.
  saveBitmap(bitmap);
```

Hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: how can i change the view's  size?  like 1260 *1660

Comment: you can set the width and height of view pragmatically right?you can make  it to any size you want .ok @user4993424 .

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)testBtn.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.width=1260;
                layoutParams.height=1660;
                testBtn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
it didn't work, it could not exceed the width of screen

Comment: If you are getting error due to exceed of size ,do one thing make your own size and change it to default after taking the bitmap.. this will work.. i think so.